# meta mask connect geth private chain

Tags: go-ethereum

My go is version 1.9 and my geth is stable version 1.8.0. I use geth to open a private chain, which can be used for mining operations, but when I use meta mask plug-in to connect to the local private chain and try to test, I always cannot connect to meta mask.
I am using two terminals to execute the following two instructions in order:

```
geth --datadir ./block01/ --networkid 15 --rpc console
geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

Here is the contents of my genese.json file：

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
},
"difficulty": "2000",
"gasLimit": "2100000",
"alloc": {
}
```

}
Below is a picture of adding a local network:
[image]